# Is there syntactic sugar for calling a function on each element of a list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, foreach, stream, syntactic-sugar

Let's say I had the following code:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
array.forEach(x => someFunc(x))
```

In Java, I know the second line could be simpler using `Stream`s (at least for static methods), like so:

```
array.stream().map(ClassName::someFunc) ...
```

Essentially I'm asking is there an analog for the `ClassName::someFunc` part in JavaScript, instead of having to write `x => someFunc(x)`?

Comment: `array.forEach(someFunc)` or using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `array.map(someFunc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, you can replace

```
array.forEach(x => someFunc(x))
```

with just

```
array.forEach(someFunc)
```

but there's some fine print you should be aware of:

- this generally doesn't work with object methods: `.forEach(someObj.someMeth)` won't work
- the callback should accept exactly one argument or conform to the `forEach` calling convention `callback(element, index, this)`.  For example, `array.map(parseInt)` won't work either, because `parseInt` has its own idea of what the second argument means.

Comment: I understand. What if I had something like an array of functions, and I wanted to call each function? Would I still be able to use `array.forEach(func)` instead of `array.forEach(func => func())`?

Comment: "this generally doesn't work with object methods" really? Why?

Comment: @yayabosh: no, you'll have to do something like `a.map(Function.call.bind(Function.call))` which is of course much worse than simply `a.map(f => f())`

Comment: @WillD: because dot notation returns an unbound function.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jp254btn/ can you provide an example of it not working or describe steps to reproduce the failure?

Comment: @WillD: try to use `this` in your method

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no need to wrap "someFunc" in an anonymous `() =>` "arrow function"

As long as someFunc's first argument is configured to accept the currently iterated item from the array and do something with it then you can pass in a reference to that function as the argument in `.forEach` (but do not call it).

So you would do:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
array.forEach(someFunc)
```

Make sure not to do this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
array.forEach(someFunc())
```

(note the calling parenthesis, this is bad)